# Layout before Firebase data is loaded

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout

I searched everywhere but couldn't find anything, how i set the loading layout before the data fetching from database...mean to show specific view before the data completely loaded.
Here is what exactly I want 
[Image](https://www.mediafire.com/view/n865j82htbtbds9/20181030_021523.png/file)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverFlow. Can you please describe what approaches you tried to resolve the problem beforehand? And also add more details to your question. Thanks

Comment: I mean I want to load a specific view  only for few seconds when the activity starts until the data from database is loaded

Comment: Please show as what you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response @NomanUddin. For quality reasons and readability, make improvement to your question instead of responding as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called [Skeleton](https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton).

**HOW TO USE IT:**

Simply use this code when you want the data to load:

```
mLoading = Skeleton.bind(yourRecyclerView)
                              .adapter(yourAdapter)
                              .load(R.layout.your_item) /* This is what you see when loading */
                              .show();
```

and then:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("yourReference")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        // your code here
                    }


                    //  Your data is finished loading by now. make sure to call notifyDataSetChanged().
                    mLoading.hide();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```